# strange conversion error when grabbing dropdownlist from form

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I've got a .net web form, back end is in vb.net. A few dropdownlists are added to the form, with their controls following the naming convention "ddlCol" + integer, so "ddlCol0", "ddlCol1", etc.

When I try and grab one of these dropdownlists to code against the control, I'm getting a conversion error from string to integer: Conversion from string "ddlCol0" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
 sDDL = "ddlCol" + iDDLControlCounter.ToString()
    Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(Me.Controls(sDDL), DropDownList)
```

I admit my vb.net is a bit rusty. Is there something dumb I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `&` if you want to concat strings in VB.NET (as oposed to C#):

```
sDDL = "ddlCol" & iDDLControlCounter.ToString()
```

However, that should not cause your conversion error. Maybe `sDDL` is declared as `Int32`.

Anyway, you should set `OPTION STRICT` to `On` because i suspect that the error is caused by an implicit conversion. Late binding should be avoided if possible.

See: [**Option Strict Statement**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Edit**: [`Controls.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a collection which has an indexer. So you can get the first control via `Me.Controls(0)`. So that is the main reason for the exception  because `sDDL` is a `String`. But thisknowledge does not help further to find your `DropDownLists`.

So read more ...

> Could the fact that these dropdowns are in the header row of a
>   gridview make a difference? I was of the mindset that a control is a
>   control is a control, but maybe there are rules I don't know about
>   with this?

No, that doesn't make a  difference. Then you would get a `NullReferenceException` when you try to use your `DropDownList`.

But you need to use `Control.FindControl` to get a reference of a control via it's ID.

If it is really in a header row of a `GridView` you have to use `FindControl` on the correct [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) which is the `HeaderRow`:

```
If grid.HeaderRow IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim ddl = DirectCast(grid.HeaderRow.FindControl("ddlCol" & iDDLControlCounter), DropDownList)
End If
```

Comment: Nope, its a string... Dim sDDL As String

Comment: And you are right, it didn't fix the conversion. Could the fact that these dropdowns are in the header row of a gridview make a difference? I was of the mindset that a control is a control is a control, but maybe there are rules I don't know about with this?

Comment: I turned Option Strict On on the page, and in the line Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(Me.Controls(sDDL), DropDownList), its trying to get me to convert sDDL to an Integer first... I'm trying to find the control by name, and sDDL is definitely a string. Am I using Me.Controls() incorrectly?

Comment: @optionsix Tim makes a few good points, but the issue is actually that Controls takes a numeric; you need FindControl, see my separate answer.

Comment: I'm not finding the control, but im wondering if its how its being appended to the gridview. Here is what the ddl looks like on the front end: <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UploadControl1$grvExcelData$ctl01$ddlCol0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UploadControl1_grvExcelData_ctl01_ddlCol0">

Comment: @optionsix: It doesn't matter how it is generated at the client, that depends on other factors like `Control.ClientIDMode`. However, `FindControl` searches the given `NamingContainer` for a control with a specified **server** ID which can be repeating in a different `NamingContainer`. So you can have on  control `ddlCol1` in every row of the `GridView` (if it's not in the header). ASP.NET will render unique ID's, but these are not relevant on serverside. So where are you trying to find these `DropDownLists`? Where did you add them(you have to use `RowCreated`).

Comment: Its a bit complicated, but the whole purpose of this is matching columns in an excel spreadsheet. So user uploads xlsx, on the _RowCreated event, we add the ddl programmatically using this logic:  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then. After the header row has a dll for each column in the sheet, we databind the data from the xlsx to the gridview. So, load xlsx -> create gridview -> ddls in header row -> bind rest of gridview to xlsx

Comment: The ddls are NOT databound to the spreadsheet btw, they have static listitems no matter what based on predetermined criteria (FirstName, LastName, etc)

Comment: @optionsix: You have to recreate the `DropDownLists` on postbacks in `RowCreated`, otherwise they will be nothing if you try to find them (e.g. in a button-click-event). Anyway, it seems to be a different problem if you cannot find them. Maybe you want to ask another question with more details.

Comment: @optionsix: The reason for your exception is that you are trying to use `Control.Controls(index)` to find your dropdown. This method retuns a collection of child controls. However, that won't help to find your Ddl's. Edited my answer anyway.

Comment: Agreed. This answer definitely fixes all of my previous problems, and gets me past the initial bug.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't with your string concatenation, but rather with your assumption about how the Controls collection works; it only takes a numeric value.

Instead, I believe the method you need to be using is FindControl:

```
sDDL = "ddlCol" & iDDLControlCounter.ToString()
Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(Me.FindControl(sDDL), DropDownList)
```

Note that if you know the precise type, DirectCast is (fractionally) faster than CType.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error in the OP is that `Me.Controls()` only takes an integer as an arguement, not a string.